# Fetch specific commit fails in shallow repositories

Tags: git, fetch, git-submodules, shallow-clone

I've a shallow clone of a submodule repository where the desired commit is on an unrelated branch to the HEAD commit.

```
git submodule update --init --depth 1
```

This works for most submodules, but the ones, where HEAD has an unrelated history to the desired commit, it fails:
When git tries to fetch the needed commit it gives the error:
`error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object`

The same error occurs also without submodules

```
git clone --depth 1 <url> prj
cd prj
git fetch origin <hash>
> error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object
```

The following works fine:

```
git clone <url> prj
cd prj
git checkout <hash>
```

Any Idea, how to get shallow submodules working when they have unrelated commits?
As we are having many submodules used with different internal structures, a manual treatment per submodule is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the server, set it up to allow fetch-by-hash-ID.

If not, stop using shallow submodules (or make them deep enough so that the problem does not occur).  That's pretty much it.